# MySQL Update of Columns using INFORMATION_SCHEMA - is this possible?

Tags: mysql, database-design, information-schema

I know that I can view the properties and do some amazing things to learn my db/table/field structure using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

However, is it possible to update a field value in for example the `COLUMNS` table and thus update the actual column?  For example setting nullable from NO to YES.

If this is not directly possible, I realize that I could use the query to CONCAT an `ALTER` string and then run those strings.  However is there in that case a way to instead run an `eval()` command to do this in one operation?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To learn INFORMATION_SCHEMA: I'd start from reading documentation - [INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html). Then I'd try to edit objects and see what happens in these tables.
2. INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables are system tables, they cannot be modified. ALTER TABLE is the only way to change a table.

Answer (score 0):

It was a beautiful idea, but unfortunately, it won't work.

The tables in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` are read-only **views**, and are not actually tables. So there aren't any files or directories associated with them. You can only read their contents and can't run `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` operations on them.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema-introduction.html#information-schema-usage-notes for the lowdown.

And FYI, there's a [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com) site if you want more targeted answers to database questions.